# css prefix for presto engine

Tags: html, css, opera, rendering-engine

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Prefix_filters) prefix for presto is **`-XV-`**

```
-xv-color: #FF0;     /* paragraphs in yellow for Presto browsers */
```

I wanted to know for presto browser the prefix is **`-O-`** or **`-XV-`**. Is Wikipedia wrong??

Comment: I believe it is -o-, but doesn't it only work on specific properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Opera documentation about [HTML and XHTML](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/html/), we document the support of `-xv-`.

> #### XHTML+Voice Profile (X+V)
>
> Opera Presto fully supports the [XHTML+Voice profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml+voice/) (and the Mobile Profile subset).
>
> - The support of X+V includes support of CSS3 Speech (with an `-xv-` prefix as this module is under preparation).
> - X+V needs to be served as an XML media type (`application/xml`, `application/xhtml+xml`, `application/x-xhtml+voice+xml`) for XML Events to take effect.
> - For more information see the [X+V developer documentation](http://my.opera.com/community/dev/voice/).

On Opera [Web Developer documentation](http://dev.opera.com/), you will find a few articles explaining [xv extension](http://dev.opera.com/search?q=xv).